# How do I SELECT this in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this setup of two tables i MySQL :

[image: schema]

How do I `SELECT` customers that have no meetings or only meetings that have meeting_held set to <> 0

Answer (score 0):

Verbose but working.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            customar_meetings
        WHERE
            customar_meetings.customar_id = customers.customar_id) 
UNION SELECT 
    *
FROM
    customers
WHERE
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            customar_meetings
        WHERE
            customar_meetings.customar_id = customers.customar_id) = 1
        AND (SELECT 
            meeting_held
        FROM
            customar_meetings
        WHERE
            customar_meetings.customar_id = customers.customar_id
        LIMIT 1) <> 0;
```